# Arduino UNO reinicia quando uso porta serial fora da IDE

Tags: c, python, arduino

Meu Arduino UNO está reiniciando quando eu uso a porta serial dele com um script Python. Mas, quando eu abro o terminal serial pela IDE do Arduino e rodo o mesmo script Python, funciona normalmente. Por que isso acontece e como resolver?

Código Arduino:

```
#define LED 10

char c;
int led = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial) {

  }
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    c = (char)Serial.read();
    Serial.println(c);
    if(c == 'a') {
      led = HIGH;
    } else if(c == 'd') {
      led = LOW;
    }
    digitalWrite(LED, led);
  }
}
```

Código Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import serial
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    command = sys.argv[1]
    ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
    if not ser.isOpen():
        ser.open()
    print command
    ser.write(command)
    ser.close()
else:
    print 'usage: luz.py a|d'
```

Comment: Verifique se você possui acesso para acessar **/dev/ttyACM0**, durante alguns testes encontrei problemas tentando acessar o Arduino sem ser root.

Comment: eu tentei isso, mas não obtive resultados, ele funciona normalmente quando o monitor serial da Arduino IDE está aberta, do contrário não.

Comment: desligue o DTR na serial via python mesmo, que provavelmente resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Estou começando com Arduino por isso não posso falar com propriedade. Porém fiz algumas pesquisas na Google e descobri que o Arduino faz um **[Auto Reset On Serial Connection](http://dqsoft.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/o-auto-reset-do-arduino.html)** depois que estabelece uma conexão serial.

Existe algumas formas de evitar isso, sendo as mais comuns o uso de [Jumper](http://wp.yellowkazoo.com/?p=177), ou efetuar [alterações na placa](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection).
O que me intriga é como a IDE consegue desligar o Auto Reset On Serial Connection sem alterar a parte fisica da placa.

Analisando uns Scripts em Python (não sei programar em Python), percebi que muitos utilizam um [loop depois de conectar na placa](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-Python-and-Arduino-with-pySerial/3/?lang=pt).

```
from time import sleep
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1d11', 9600)
while True:
    ser.write(Dados) 
    print ser.readline() 
    sleep(.1)
```

Isso faz com que os dados sejam enviados a todo momento, dessa forma depois da placa reiniciar (se ela reiniciar). Os dados estarão disponíveis.

Outra método que achei bem valido é que você poderia fazer o `setup` do [Arduino escrever na portal serial que ele esta pronto](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=06rm2ncli8ncf69fgqiafuji71&topic=18371.msg133805#msg133805). E ficar aguardando esta mensagem no script Python.
Somente depois de receber esta mensagem que você enviaria a mensagem para a placa. De acordo com outros usuários esta opção funciona de forma perfeita.

Caso precise de mais informações sobre como desativar o reset no Hardware você pode visitar este [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24743/arduino-resetting-while-reconnecting-the-serial-terminal).